# What is the correct way to play a sound file using java.sound.sampled.Clip

Tags: java, file, audio, jar, nullpointerexception

I have read many SoF threads and other sites on this topic, but none of them works for me, so I am asking again, hoping to receive tailored answer.

I have a .WAV file inside my jar what I want to play, but I am getting `NullPointerException.`
I have tried many ways, even playing file outside the jar via absolute path, but I got the same result.
This is the function for playing the sound

```
public void gimli(){
        try {
            Clip clip;
             AudioInputStream  stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource(Utils.class.getResourceAsStream("gimlilaught.wav").toString()));
   AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
  clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    clip.open(stream);
    clip.start();
}catch(Exception ex){
ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

Thank you for your trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `AudioInputStream` is needed as an argument for opening a `Clip`. Looking at the API, you will see that either [AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(InputStream)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream-java.io.InputStream-) or [AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(URL)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream-java.net.URL-) can be used to get an *AudioInputStream*.

There are two methods of `Class` that serve: `getResource(String)` or `getResourceAsStream(String)`. The *getResource* method will return a `URL`. The *getResourceAsStream* method will return an `InputStream`.

I prefer using the URL form, as it is more forgiving. When using *AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(InputStream)*, an `IOException` will be returned if the file does not support *marking* and *resetting*. The method *AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(URL)* circumvents this requirement.

Also, you should be aware that a `URL`, unlike a `File`, can be used to identify a file that is within jar.

You also have to be careful about setting the relative address. I generally like to have a */res* file or */audio* file that holds the .wav to be loaded. For example, you can use "**../res/myAudio.wav**" if */res* is a parallel folder or "**res/myAudio.wav**" if */res* is subfolder, relative to the location of the class being used in the *getResource* method.

Here is a simple working example, where the audio file is in a subfolder, */res*:

```
private static void loadAndPlayClip() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, 
        IOException, LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException
{
    String filename = "a3.wav";
    URL url = BasicClipExample.class.getResource("res/" + filename);
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, ais.getFormat());
    Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    clip.open(ais);

    clip.start();
    Thread.sleep(7000); // Duration should match length of audio file.
    clip.close();
}
```

While this example should work, it shouldn't be used *as is* in production, for two reasons.

1. The `Thread.sleep()` command halts the main thread, which is usually neither desirable nor needed. The thread that the system creates for `Clip` playback is a [daemon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) thread. *Daemon* threads will not prevent a program from completing and shutting down. In this simple "fire and forget" example the main thread is quickly done, so the program will immediately shut down if we don't stave off completion with a sleep interval.
2. The initial loading of a `Clip` and the playing of a `Clip` are usually done in two separate methods. A `Clip` was designed for audio that can be conveniently held in memory, allowing it to be replayed without requiring reloading. If you reload the `Clip` with each play command, you would be both redoing work that is not needed and adding latency, as the clip will not begin playing until it has been entirely loaded. If the audio file is inconvenient to hold in memory (e.g., large file due to long duration), the preferred method is to play it with a `SourceDataLine`.

Comment: The code works until I get NullPoiterException, but it looks like the error is on my side. Thank you for your answer, I'll look at it more deeply.

Comment: What line is the NPE?

Comment: Ok, finally I got this `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface Clip supporting format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian is supported.` what exactly does that mean?

Comment: The npe was on this line `Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);` but I think it's solved now, I have the second thing, `no line matching interface Clip supporting...`

Comment: Curious. The format you described (44100 fps, 16-bit, stereo, signed PCM, little-endian) is a super common standard, often described as "CD Quality". It makes little sense that your system would not support this. If you run AudioSystem.getAudioFileTypes(), is .WAV included as what your OS supports? From the code you've shown, you should be using the default mixer. You might check what mixers are on your system, for clues. This tutorial has background and the next in series shows how to query. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/sampled-overview.html

Comment: The problem was that Android isn't designed to run JAVA SE, on PC it works fine. Thank you all for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying this last night and what seems to work for me is:

```
try {
            File filePath = new File(audioLocation);

            if (filePath.exists()) {
                AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(filePath);
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audioInput);
                FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
                gainControl.setValue(getVolume());
                clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
                clip.start();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect audio file path!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Although I think I should have clip.open() in there somewhere and I've had issues stopping and starting the audio from another class, this does get the sound to play.

Comment: Thanks for response. How does your file path look like?

Comment: @BlackDragon I actually changed from this system to get rid of File filePath = new File(audioLocation); entirely. I now use a URL for the path and just use that directly if that makes sense. This way when you compile to a runnable Jar the audio actually plays. I just created a *package* called res and put it inside ("/res/audio.wav")

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly where my audio is. I'll try it.